# Must copy and rename file

Tags: rename

Hi all i was asked to find the terminal command that will make a copy of a file lets call it program3.cpp  and give to the copy the name homework6.cpp.  After that you will have two files with different names, but identical contents.

I know how to copy the file but i cant figure out how to create a second identical file with a different name. 
All help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I love the irony of renaming `program` to `homework` on SE

Answer (score 91):

Copy and rename in the same time (also change filename, not only path):

```
cp program3.cpp homework6.cpp
```

Rename only:

```
mv program3.cpp homework6.cpp
```

Comment: Ah... I hate `cp` only supports "copy and rename" in the same dir; when you copy to another location, the destination can only be a dir, not the target file name.. and you must `cp` first and then `mv`.

Comment: @WesternGun That's not true. `cp /opt/MyFile /tmp/MyNewNamedFile`
What you CAN'T do is to copy a file from another location to your current location and rename it at the same time here (`.`) . (As far as I know)

Comment: @DimiDak sure you can: `cp ~/make/makefiles/rails_makefile ./Makefile` renames the file rails_makefile to Makefile in the current directory :) (well, at least on macOS it does, maybe linux is different?)

Comment: @stevec Yeap, that worked :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have the files permanently linked use the `ln` command instead of `cp`

```
ln program3.cpp homework6.cpp
```

This puts a file descriptor (hard link) under the name `homework6.cpp` to the same file location as `program3.cpp`